# Airdrop showing wrong name

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad Pro running version 12.1.1. In Settings the name shows properly as Charles's iPad but when I try to airdrop photos it shows on other devices as John iPad.  I see nowhere to change this?  Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you are airdropping to the right iPad?

Comment: Check if John is set as the nickname in address book entry corresponding to the logged in Apple ID’s contact. The nickname is shown when AirDropping if Prefer Nicknames is enabled under Settings app -> Contacts -> Short Name.

Answer (score 6):

Finally fixed this. All the settings on my iPhone were correct, but my iMac kept thinking my phone had a different name (my son's). Took me a while, but figured out that my iMac was using my iCloud contacts, which I don't sync to my phone. I tracked down a stray listing for my son and deleted it, and now my iMac recognizes my phone correctly. So double check all your contact listings, both on your phone/iPad and in iCloud!

Comment: This was annoying me for ages. Thank you!